# How to disable the Error Hovers/Code Mining in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I think this is something that is released lately in Eclipse 2021. These error hovers/code minings are really annoying. Sometimes, they overlap the code also, and the code moves a lot.

[image]

Does anybody know how to disable this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referred to as "code mining".  I came to the same conclusion as you. They were intriguing at first, but they became more of an annoyance over time.

If you search for "mining" in Eclipse Preferences, you'll see the two places where code mining can be controlled, but I believe just unchecking "Enable code minings ..." in "Java->Editor->CodeMinings" will do it.

[image: Disable Code Mining in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

While searching the web for the same issue, I landed on this [discussion](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=553849) and the following steps worked for me. Please note that I do not want to completely disable it. Just wanted to disable the annoying code jumping when I am typing the code.

You can actually do that, although the UI does not support it.

1. Close your Eclipse
2. Open file in a text editor:
   /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
3. Find the line (it's only added once you changed your code mining settings)
   showAnnotationAsCodeMiningLevel=
4. After the equals sign, you'll find a number.
   The number encodes in binary:

> ```
> 1110b
>    | no code minings
>   | code minings for infos
>  | code minings for warnings
> | code minings for errors
> ```

However, it's stored in decimal, so you have to convert it.
If you want no errors, but warnings and infos as code minings:
0110b = 6d

5. Change the line to
   **showAnnotationAsCodeMiningLevel=6**
6. Save the file
7. Start Eclipse

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help me with Eclipse 2022-06 + Corrosion.